# Как вывести данные таблицей c++

Tags: c++

при вводе данных структура колонок сбивается, не могу найти в интернете как сделать аккуратно всё.
Может подскажите, как вообще работает вот это :  **%19s | %11.2lf | %5d | %17s |\n**

```
void print_goods(good *goods, int size) {
    printf("+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+------------+|------------+------------+------------+------------|\n");
    printf("|         name        |    price    |  count     |  genre    |  developer  |    year    +   min_cpu  | min_ram    |   min_hdd  | \n");
    printf("+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------|------------+|------------+------------+------------+------------|\n");

    if (size == 0)
        printf("|            No goods was added...          |\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("| %19s | %11.2lf | %5d | %17s |\n", goods[i].name, goods[i].price, goods[i].count,goods[i].title);

    printf("+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------|------------+|------------+------------+------------+------------|\n");
}
```

Comment: данные не все в printf, не успел еще добавить, но на колонке genre все плыть начинает

Comment: Дык а в чем конкретно вопрос? [Мануал](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) на `printf` смотрели?

Comment: вопрос:как построить таблицу для вывода данных

Comment: может есть более простой способ нежели рисовать черточки и столбики

Comment: Нет, более простого способа нет. *"вопрос:как построить таблицу"* На первый взгляд вы уже все правильно делаете. Если что-то плывет, поправьте числа (ширины столбцов), которые отправляете в `printf`.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, тогда буду стараться